# How can I create a reliable test Facebook Messenger channel for MS Azure Bot?

Tags: facebook, botframework, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I created a demo Chatbot app for Facebook Messenger using MS Bot Framework. From what I have gathered, Messenger apps can only be tied to Facebook Pages. So I created a sample test Page and configured as the Messenger channel.

Facebook just unpublished the page due to TOC violation. I believe it's on the ground that the page is not complete / it has "misleading" information.

What's the best approach to create a reliable Messenger channel for testing & demo purposes?

Thanks!

Comment: Follow the TOC... I have a page for the same purpose for months now, still valid

Comment: I have read the TOC and I cannot identify any rule that we may have violated. The only remotely relevant rule is not having "fake" content. Our page had a cover, a picture and a name -- but, obviously the page name is not a real business name.

Comment: @Naz Did you use an actual Facebook account to create the page?  Facebook doesn't allow developers to have a development account: they expect you to use your actual account.  Meaning, you can't create a facebook account solely for a page or bot.

Comment: Yes, I used my personal Facebook account.